# Inconsistent list label-dots with Arabic using polyglossia

Tags: enumerate, polyglossia, arabic

I am using polyglossia to write document with Arabic and English. I have an enumerate field. The problem is that if the last word prior was English, the dot is placed on the right instead of the left of the item number. This problem does not occur if the English word is not last in the sentence of the \item. Compare the second and third points in:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script = Arabic]{Baghdad} 

\begin{document}

اجابات الأسئلة
\begin{enumerate}
%
\item الاجابة هي:
\textenglish{Thank you}.

%
\item \textenglish{was} هو فعل ماضي.

%
\item مقولة صحيحة.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I want everything to be like the first \item.
[image: This is my code product.]

Comment: Works for me. Tested also with `babel`/`xetex` (with changes, of course), which relies in the `bidi` package, too. Maybe an old version of the latter?